# putting a tikzpicture inside a \caption{}

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I'm attempting to put a small `tikzpicture` inside a `\caption{}` belonging to a `figure` environment. The reason for doing this is fairly simple - to create an in-caption legend for a PGFplot, with consistency between the TikZ styles in the figure and in the caption. Previously I would have done this using dashes and the `xcolor` package, however, this is an awful hack. In this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\raisebox{0.5ex}{
\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[dashed,color=red,thick] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);\end{tikzpicture}}
Gas--Phase} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The expected output:

[image: an example of my expected output]

is generated, but I get `! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.` and `! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.` Within the larger context of the document that I'm writing, which includes chapters in external .tex files, compilation fails catastrophically (dozens of errors) with no output, so I can't just ignore the warnings in this instance. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that it would be better to directly put the legends in the plot rather than in the caption.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PGFplots has this feature built-in already: You can assign `\label`s to your plots, and then use `\ref` in the figure caption (or anywhere else) to get a legend picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [red, dashed, thick] {x+rand}; \label{gasphase}
\addplot [black] {x}; \label{straightline}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A simple diagram: \ref{gasphase} Gas--Phase;  \ref{straightline} A straight line}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, that works wonderfully. Never spotted that in the manual.

Comment: The solution proposed is smart.

Comment: Very nice! But what happens if I make my tikzpicture in an external file and call it from within main.tex where the figure environment is located?

Comment: @HCAI: Do you mean that you're putting the `tikzpicture` into an external `.tex` file that you include using `\input` (or `\include`) (in that case it should just work), or do you mean that you're compiling the `tikzpicture` into a separate `.pdf` file using the `external` library? In that case, things are a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Jake The latter. I create a standalone tikzpic.tex file and call it using \input and compile using external library. It's necessary because the pictures are so big. Is it a complicated procedure?