# Placing graphics inside figure captions

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

Similar to [putting a tikzpicture inside a \caption{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33274/putting-a-tikzpicture-inside-a-caption), I would like to insert an external icon inside figure captions, something like:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{text with \includegraphics{icon} somewhere inside}
\includegraphics{image}
\end{figure}
```

How might this be done?

Comment: Can you please post an image of a sample of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to protect `\includegraphics` inside `\caption`; this, however, will add the image also to a possible list of figures, so perhaps you would rather use the optional argument of `\caption`; in this case, no protection is needed. The following example code shows both alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{text with \protect\includegraphics[height=1cm]{icon} somewhere inside}
  \includegraphics{image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption[text for the LoF]{text with \includegraphics[height=1cm]{icon} somewhere inside}
  \includegraphics{image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that answers my question perfectly. Both options worked, either using the `\protect` command or including the `\caption[LoF]{}` format. Thanks!