# Referencing gnuplot epslatex symbols in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

The situation I am faced with is that I need to write a caption for a figure created with `gnuplot`, where I wish to reference the point types used by `gnuplot` in the actual plot, something akin to "Results with 1% (X), 5% (O) and 10% (^) are shown," where X, O and ^ stand for the symbols used.

**Question:** Is there a standard way of dealing with this?

I am fine when it comes to colors, but can't figure out how to get the precise symbols used by the `epslatex` terminal. [In this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146398/plot-symbols-from-r-as-latex-symbols), the similar problem of dealing with `R`-generated plots was considered and the answer suggests to output a PDF with a single symbol.

For a moment I hoped that the `epslatex` symbols are actually taken from some sort of font, since I saw similar characters in Symbola. Unfortunately, a quick look at the EPS output shows that each symbol is actually drawn using PostScript:

```
/TriU {stroke [] 0 setdash 2 copy vpt 1.12 mul add M
  hpt neg vpt -1.62 mul V
  hpt 2 mul 0 V
  hpt neg vpt 1.62 mul V closepath stroke
  Pnt} def
```

The above sample defines the triangle pointing up symbol.

**Question:** Would there be any way of using such PostScript snippets within LaTeX or would I need to make my own list of tiny EPS files for each such symbol?

**Question:** If I indeed went the hard way of making EPS files for the symbols, is there at least a way of changing the color of the included EPS file or would I need to make separate EPS file for each color variant of a given symbol?

Comment: You could use the `lua tikz` terminal, which uses standard TikZ point types, so that you could use those in your caption.

Comment: Any one has any update on this issue ?