# How to put a \pgfuseshading object inside a caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I would like to put a pgf object, `\pgfuseshading{}`, inside the caption of a figure or table. The below code creates this pgf object which can be created in in the text (`\pgfuseshading{CyanToBlue}`) of the document but causes errors when put inside the caption (`\caption {\pgfuseshading{spectrumRedToBlue}}`).

Any help putting this pgf object in the caption of the table would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{CyanToBlue}{0.25cm}{color(0cm)=(Cyan); color(0.6cm)=(Blue)}                                                                                                                                                   

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spectrumRedToBlue}{0.25cm}{color(0cm)=(Red); 
color(0.15cm)=(Orange);
color(0.25cm)=(Yellow);
color(0.35cm)=(SpringGreen);
color(0.45cm)=(Cyan);
color(0.65cm)=(Blue)} 

\begin{document}

 \pgfuseshading{CyanToBlue} 

\begin{table}
 \caption {Geometry \pgfuseshading{spectrumRedToBlue} }
\begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{l c c c }
    \hline\hline
    Atom & x ($\AA{}$) & y ($\AA{}$) & z ($\AA{}$) \\ \hline
      C & -0.32   & -0.878  & -0.7512 \\ 

    \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}
\label{tab:} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\protect` ...

```
\caption{Geometry \protect\pgfuseshading{spectrumRedToBlue}}
```

... to get:
[image]

How it works is nicely described in [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4747/124842).
But then it will also appear in the table of content. See for an other solution to a similar problem [Placing graphics inside figure captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54051/124842). So if it should not appear in toc you could use `\caption[Geometry]{Geometry \pgfuseshading{spectrumRedToBlue} or \pgfuseshading{CyanToBlue}}` instead.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{CyanToBlue}{0.25cm}{color(0cm)=(Cyan); color(0.6cm)=(Blue)}                                                                                                                                                   
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spectrumRedToBlue}{0.25cm}{color(0cm)=(Red); 
color(0.15cm)=(Orange);color(0.25cm)=(Yellow);color(0.35cm)=(SpringGreen);
color(0.45cm)=(Cyan);color(0.65cm)=(Blue)} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption {Geometry \protect\pgfuseshading{spectrumRedToBlue} or  \protect\pgfuseshading{CyanToBlue}  }
%\caption[Geometry]{Geometry \pgfuseshading{spectrumRedToBlue} or \pgfuseshading{CyanToBlue}}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c }
    \hline\hline
    Atom & x ($\AA{}$) & y ($\AA{}$) & z ($\AA{}$) \\ \hline
      C & -0.32   & -0.878  & -0.7512 \\ 
    \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```