# How to insert an image in a caption

Tags: graphics, captions

I'm trying to insert a picture in the caption to illustrate something. How can I do that?

Currently, I use the following code, the tex engine prompts uncontrolled sequence error.

```
\caption{Some caption words. \raisebox{-0.4\height}{\includegraphics[width=1em]{fig}} some other caption words.}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which reproduce your problem. Try the following `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some caption words. \protect\includegraphics[width=1em, height=2ex]{fig} some other caption words.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}` (observe command `protect`!)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Placing graphics inside figure captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54049/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want the image in the list of tables so use

```
\caption[short form]{long form with \includegraphics{...}}
```

The the fragile commands will not be in the "moving argument" used for the table of contents, and the errors will go.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a loooot!