# How to put a legend for \cellcolor{blue!25} in my table caption?

Tags: tables, color

I would like to put a reference to  `\cellcolor{blue!25}` in the table's caption. Is it possible? Also why is the table so massive even in a `makebox`? I don't want to use resize, looks unprofessional.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[t]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
     \toprule
     &\multicolumn{6}{c}{Care Type} \\
     \midrule
     \vspace{3pt}
     &\textbf{Direct care} & \textbf{Housekeeping} & \textbf{Mealtimes} & \textbf{Medication rounds} & \textbf{Miscellaneous} & \textbf{Personal care} &\textbf{Overall} \\
    \textbf{Correlation coefficient $r$} & 0.525 &   0.580   & 0.914 &   0.678 &   0.333 &   0.103& 0.5663\\
    \textbf{p-value} & \cellcolor{blue!25}$ <$0.001 &  \cellcolor{blue!25} 0.015 & \cellcolor{blue!25}  $<$0.001 & \cellcolor{blue!25}  $<$0.001  & \cellcolor{blue!25} 0.004 &   0.7378& \cellcolor{blue!25}$ <$0.001\\
      \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}}
     \label{tab:r_p_vals}
     \caption{Correlation coefficients and p-values for time versus surface contacts. Where \cellcolor{blue!25} represents a statistically significant value }
     \end{table}
```

Comment: Why don't just use words: `Where the values in the blue cells represent a statistically significant value.`?

Comment: `\makebox` doesn't affect the size of the table (it just hides it and allows it to stick into the margins) This version is wide as you have gone back to `c` columns which do not allow line breaking so each column is as wide as its heading. In previous questions with this same table you had `p` columns that allowed the headings to wrap.

Comment: Thank you both DavidCarlisle & @GonzaloMedina. I found this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33274/putting-a-tikzpicture-inside-a-caption which looks quite nice but we're not using tikz. Perhaps those blue cells don't actually look very professional.